# How can I get information about droped and replaced transaction in web3?

Tags: ethereum, web3py

I am using web3.py.

1. How can I get info about droped and replaced transaction?
2. How can I get info about pending transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out more information of the transaction using getTransaction
and getTransactionReceipt.

Pending transactions can only be found through getTransaction but not  getTransactionReceipt.

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html?highlight=gettransaction#web3.eth.Eth.getTransaction

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html?highlight=gettransaction#web3.eth.Eth.getTransactionReceipt